# JavaScript can not get alert box

Tags: javascript

So basically, I'm trying to do client side validation through JavaScript, but the code does not seem to be working. I am not getting any alert box. Below is HTML Form and JavaScript. I have skipped html and Body tags for obvious reasons. Can someone look over and see where am I making a mistake?

HTML form

```
<div class="container" >
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Online Vaccine Registration Form</h1>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Developed by yourname</h1>
    
        
            <form method="post" name="vacform" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
                <table>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Name">Name : </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
        
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="CNIC" >CNIC : </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CNIC"  placeholder="CNIC">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Mob">Mobile : </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Mob" placeholder="Mobile">
                </div>
        
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Dob" >DoB : </label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="DoB">
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cen">Nearby centre</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                  <option selected disabled>Select your Nearest Centre</option>  
                  <option>Karachi West</option>
                  <option>Karachi East</option>
                  <option>Karachi North</option>
                  <option>Karachi Central</option>
                  <option>Malir</option>
                </select>
              </div>
                </table>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
            function validateForm() 
            {
              var varname = document.vacform.name.value;
              var varcnic = document.vacform.CNIC.value;
              var varMob = document.vacform.Mob.value;
              var varDoB = new Date(DoB);
              var limitdate = new Date('2010-01-01');
    
              var CNlength = 13;
              var num = /^[0-9]+$/;
              var str = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    
              if(document.vacform.name.value!="")
              {
                  if(document.vacform.CNIC.value!="")
                  {
                      if(document.vacform.Mob.value!="")
                      {
                          if(document.vacform.DoB.value!="")
                          {
                            if(varname.match(str))
                            {
                              if(varcnic.lenght == CNlength)
                              {
                                  if(varcnic.match(num)) 
                                  {
                                    if(varDoB.getYear() < limitdate.getYear())
                                    {
                                      alert("All types of Validations have been done")
                                      return true;
                                    }    
                                    else
                                    {
                                      alert("Date should be less than 01-01-2010")
                                      return false;
                                    }
                                  }
                                else
                                {
                                  alert("CNIC field should have numbers only")
                                  return false; 
                                }
                              }
                            else
                            {
                                alert("CNIC lenght should be 13")
                                return false; 
                            }  
                            }
                         else
                         {
                            alert("Name can only contain letters")
                            return false;  
                         }   
                          }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Date of Birth must be entered")
                            return false;
                        }
                      }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Please Enter your mobile number")
                        return false;
                    }
                  }
                else
                {
                    alert("CNIC number Required")
                    return false;
                }
            
              }
    
       else
       {
        alert("Name field can not be empty")
              return false;
       }
    }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should just debug this by logging what the individual values are until you find out why your tests do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function from the `onsubmit` event handler, however **you never submit the form** so it can't be triggered.

> ```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
> ```

This kind of button is for hooking JS into. It isn't a submit button.

Set `type="submit"` or remove the `type` attribute entirely (`submit` is the default).

Also address the errors in your HTML that [a validator](https://validator.nu/) would highlight.